# Joomla 1.5: How to find a view given a template? Reverse engineering a site

Tags: templates, joomla, view, joomla1.5, reverse-engineering

I'm facing the task of reverse engineering a LARGE Joomla site -- to make changes and additions.

I can find which template is behind a page fairly easily. However finding which view file is feeding variable values to that template is proving difficult.

Any tips or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misconceptions about how Joomla! templates work in 1.5.

Templates aren't passed values by the views they are displaying.

Templates are just that, a template that is processed by Joomla which looks for the `<jdoc>` tags and effectively replaces them with the output generated by the `component` and any `modules` that are displayed on the page. (Plug-ins can also process page content but thats a lower level).

For example you will find these `jdoc` statements in the `rhuk_milkyway` template that ships with Joomla! 1.5.x

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" />
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="rounded" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml"/>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml"/>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="syndicate" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
```

To find out what generates the content in a particular position on a page you will need to determine if it's a module or the main component. If it's a component generating the content (this is usually what generates the main body of a Joomla! page) then you can find the settings for the component in its menu item.

If it's a module generating the section of the page you're interested in the you will need to open the `Menu Manager` and then find the relevant module and open that to get it's settings.